# The location of the fulcrum is different from the location of the center of mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, equilibrium

There is a problem in my homework that  went:

> The fulcrum of a uniform 20-kg seesaw that is 4.0 m long is located
>   2.5 m from one end. A 27-kg child sits on the long end. Determine the mass a person at the other end would have to be in order to balance
>   the seesaw.

The problem (I think) assumes that the center of mass is at exactly at $x = 2.0 \ m$, which I couldn't see a priori, since the equations for the center of mass (ass given by my book) seems to depend on what exactly $m_ix_i$ already are. Since we have an unknown $m_i$, how do we know that the center of mass is at $x = 2.0 \ m$?

[image]

(Sorry if this question is too trivial.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the seesaw is described as a:

> uniform 20-kg seesaw

so by symmetry the centre of mass must be exactly halfway along it.